# Bash scripting to copy

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Please share any bash script to run s3 copy commands. I have already tried separate Script to call the rclone command for each agency to backup EC2 instance windows server data to S3.

Answer (score 2):

The command below syncs the current directory to an S3 bucket using a named profile.

```sh
aws s3 sync . $S3_BUCKET_URL --profile $YOUR_PROFILE_BRO
```

The next command syncs the S3 bucket to the current directory using a named profile.

```sh
aws s3 sync $S3_BUCKET_URL . --profile $YOUR_PROFILE_BRO
```

The next command copies a file (`file.txt`) from your machine to S3 using the default profile of your machine.

```sh
aws s3 cp file.txt s3://my-bucket/
```

Of course, you need an `aws-cli` and AWS credential pair (secret key & secret key id) to make this work from your machine or on-premise networks. If you want to copy from EC2 to S3, you can assign IAM roles that posses permissions to write/read objects to that EC2 and you should be good to go.